# Padding have a effect on ::after

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I want to create a list item, with only one class.

But all what I do have an effect on ::after and ::before. How can I prevent that?

For example, force ::after stand still and increase the padding of the class?

```
    .magic {
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      background: #57ab27;
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding-top: 6px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: "Arial", Arial, Sans-serif;
    }

    .magic::before {
      content: "\f067";
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-decoration: inherit;
      /*--adjust as necessary--*/

      display: block;
      color: #FFF;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding-right: 0.5em;
      position: absolute;
      top: 17px;
      left: 20px;
    }

    .magic::after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 5px;
      height: 36px;
      background: white;
      position: relative;
      left: 40px;
      top: -29px;
    }
```

http://codepen.io/loose11/pen/doyvBv

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried negative margins or absolute positioning?

Comment: Are trying to do this- http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/mJdmbq It's really not clear from your question what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I develop an angularjs app and have to change the state of this row for specific events. Currently we have 4 css-classes for this row and it is pretty hard to react on every event with other css-classes. So I tought, the row can be done with only one css class. Thank you Paulie_D